# using Theano.scan for iterating over ndarray with a condition

Tags: python, theano, theano.scan

Pardon me for a basic question(I am new to Theano)!

I want to get the difference of 2 matrices for only those positions that satisfy a condition. So, suppose we have 2 matrices A and B, this(python equivalent code) is what I want to calculate:

```
sum = 0
n,m = A.shape
for i in xrange(n):
    for j in xrange(m):
        if(A[i][j] != 3.5):        #some random condition!
            sum += A[i][j] - B[i][j]
```

I want a Theano equivalent code to calculate the *sum*.
I know there is **Theano.scan** that can be used to scan an *ndarray*, but I could not get any example that has an if condition.
Thank you in advance :)